# Rspec test failing with capybara even though save_and_open_page is correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

Here's the relevant test:

```
#spec/requests/posts_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Posts pages" do
  subject { page }
  describe "edit" do
    let (:post) { Post.order('release_date desc').first }
    before do 
        visit posts_path
        within(:css, "div#post_#{post.id}") { click_link "Edit" }
        save_and_open_page # has correct title
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', "Editing #{post.title}" ) } # fails
  end
end
```

The failure message:

```
1) Posts pages edit 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', "Editing #{post.title}" ) }
   expected css "Editing unde inventore illo accusamus" to return something
```

However, when the page opens in my browser via `save_and_open_page`, the title is correct and it has opened the correct `edit` page.  I double-checked for any typos in the template vs. the test, and it matches up.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Try using the debugger and play with your data to determine if something is missing or incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for `have_selector` is wrong. Try this:

```
it { should have_selector('title', :text => "Editing #{post.title}" ) }
```

Comment: Goodness.  I had a feeling it was something simple.  I really need to stop coding at the end of the day.  Thanks!